# Combinations of size k from a list in OCaml

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

I wanted to write a small but non-trivial function in OCaml to test my understanding. I have only a basic understanding of the libraries, and no idea at all of what is considered good style. The function computes all combinations of size `k` from a list, where `0 <= k <= length lst`.

Would someone mind commenting on

1. Whether the function is generally well written (have I covered all cases, are there opportunities for tail recursion that I've missed?)
2. Have I made good use of libraries (e.g. I defined `is_empty` and `tails` because I couldn't find them in the `List` module, but maybe they are somewhere else?)
3. Is the style okay, particularly the use of `let` statements and indentation?

The code is:

```
let rec tails = function
  | []          -> []
  | _ :: t as l -> l :: tails t

let is_empty = function
  | [] -> true
  | _  -> false

let rec combnk k lst =
  if k = 0 then [[]]
  else let f = function
    | []      -> [] (* I think this is unnecessary, but I get a pattern match warning o/w *)
    | x :: xs -> List.map (fun z -> x :: z) (combnk (k-1) xs)
  in if is_empty lst then []
     else List.concat (List.map f (tails lst))
```

---

Based on the excellent comments by amon (see below) I have written to what I think is the most readable version of this function, which is the one that inlines the definition of `tails` and gets rid of `is_empty` completely, but doesn't go all the way to removing the use of `List.concat` and `List.map`, because I believe in using library functions to simplify the code wherever possible.

In particular, the layout guidelines make the structure of the function much clearer, and I think that in this version it is obvious what algorithm is being used, whereas it is somewhat obfuscated in the original. Thanks, amos!

```
let rec combnk k lst =
  if k = 0 then
    [[]]
  else
    let rec inner = function
      | []      -> []
      | x :: xs -> List.map (fun z -> x :: z) (combnk (k - 1) xs) :: inner xs in
    List.concat (inner lst)
```

Comment: Like many, I tend to align the rhs of match arrows, but this style is actually discouraged from the official guidelines: http://caml.inria.fr/resources/doc/guides/guidelines.en.html#idp1191136

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `tails` is very beatiful, your `is_empty` useless, and `combnk` a mess.

In `combnk`, your indentation obfuscates the actual structure of the code. Here is a better indentation:

```
let rec combnk k lst =
  if k = 0 then
    [[]]
  else
    let f = function
      | []      -> []
      | x :: xs -> List.map (fun z -> x :: z) (combnk (k - 1) xs)
    in
      if is_empty lst then
        []
      else
        List.concat (List.map f (tails lst))
```

Now there are some interesting observations to be made here: The branch `if is_empty lst then []` does not access `f`, so we could move this test outside of the `let`:

```
let rec combnk k lst =
  if k = 0 then
    [[]]
  else if is_empty lst then
    []
  else
    let f = function
      | []      -> []
      | x :: xs -> List.map (fun z -> x :: z) (combnk (k - 1) xs)
    in
      List.concat (List.map f (tails lst))
```

But is the `is_empty` test actually necessary? `tails []` produces an empty list, `List.map f []` produces an empty list for any function `f`, and `List.concat []` also produces an empty list. We now have:

```
let rec combnk k lst =
  if k = 0 then
    [[]]
  else
    let f = function
      | []      -> []
      | x :: xs -> List.map (fun z -> x :: z) (combnk (k - 1) xs)
    in
      List.concat (List.map f (tails lst))
```

How can this be improved? We can move the `tails` definitions inside the else-branch `let` so that it's restricted to the only scope where it is used:

```
let rec combnk k lst =
  if k = 0 then
    [[]]
  else
    let rec tails = function
      | []          -> []
      | _ :: t as l -> l :: tails t
    and f = function
      | []      -> []
      | x :: xs -> List.map (fun z -> x :: z) (combnk (k - 1) xs)
    in
      List.concat (List.map f (tails lst))
```

Regarding the question whether the case `[] -> []` in `f` is necessary except for the type system: The answer is *no*, as the list produced by `tails` cannot contain another empty list – `l :: []` is `l` again. This would change when you swap `[] -> []` in `tails` for `[] -> [[]]`, which would be arguably more correct.

Now that `f` and `tails` are so close together you may notice some similarities.  Indeed, we can combine the two directly, thus getting rid of one `map`:

```
let rec combnk k lst =
  if k = 0 then
    [[]]
  else
    let rec inner = function
      | []      -> []
      | x :: xs -> (List.map (fun z -> x :: z) (combnk (k - 1) xs)) :: inner xs
    in
      List.concat (inner lst)
```

Of course, `inner` could be made partially tail recursive (but this reverses the order of combinations):

```
let rec combnk k lst =
  if k = 0 then
    [[]]
  else
    let rec inner acc = function
      | []      -> acc
      | x :: xs ->
        let this_length = List.map (fun z -> x :: z) (combnk (k - 1) xs)
        in
          inner (this_length :: acc) xs
    in
      List.concat (inner [] lst)
```

There is still an indirect recursion through `combnk`, more obvious if we rewrite it like this:

```
let rec combnk k lst =
  let rec inner acc k lst =
    match k with
    | 0 -> [[]]
    | _ ->
      match lst with
      | []      -> List.flatten acc
      | x :: xs ->
        let this_length = List.map (fun z -> x :: z) (inner [] (k - 1) xs)
        in
          inner (this_length :: acc) k xs
  in
    inner [] k lst
```

Now all that is left to do is to write a `map` that takes an external accumulator, thus also removing the need for `flatten` or `concat`:

```
let rec combnk k lst =
  let rec inner acc k lst =
    match k with
    | 0 -> [[]]
    | _ ->
      match lst with
      | []      -> acc
      | x :: xs ->
        let rec accmap acc f = function
          | []      -> acc
          | x :: xs -> accmap ((f x) :: acc) f xs
        in
          let newacc = accmap acc (fun z -> x :: z) (inner [] (k - 1) xs)
          in
            inner newacc k xs
    in
      inner [] k lst
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think your version with `tails` inlined (fifth code block) is clearest.